# Is "re-rendezvous" repetitive?

Tags: etymology

I recently used the word **re-rendezvous** in conversation with several people, meaning for two entities to come together again after having initially met and gone their separate ways. (This was a software engineering discussion, in which everything is conceptual and we frequently use metaphors.)  Someone said "'Re-rendezvous' - wouldn't that be redundant?", implying that the *re* of *rendezvous* meant "again."  I've looked at several definitions and etymologies, and all I can see is that *rendez vous* means "present yourselves" in Middle French.  I don't get any "again-ness."

I'll admit it was a clunky invention, made up on the spot in a casual conversation, but I don't think it was "redundant."  And it occurs to me: doesn't the *re* prefix always occupy a syllable of its own when it means "again"?  As, say, "redundant" derives from *re* + *undare*, according to [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=redundant)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your analysis is correct. As you mentioned, [*rendezvous*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/rendezvous) simply means to meet or assemble and does not imply that this is happening again. You use the word *rendezvous* to refer to an event that has only occurred once.

So *re-rendezvous* is not redundant; it just sounds odd (as any *re-re-* word does as in *re-remedy* or *re-resent*). It definitely sounds more natural to say *rendezvous again*.

Answer (score 1):

***Chambers*** (http://www.chambersharrap.co.uk/) defines ***rendezvous***, *inter alia*, as "to meet at an appointed place or time" and specifies:
"ETYMOLOGY: 16c: French, meaning 'present yourselves', from *se rendre* to present oneself."

I agree that the "*re*" in ***rendezvous*** does not mean "again", any more than does the "*re*" in "*remain*", "*respect*" and other words that 'happen' to begin with "*re*". It follows that the "*re-*" in ***re-rendezvous*** is not redundant.

But, yes, it is 'clunky', and, unless you were actually agreeing "an appointed place or time", it would seem that ***rendezvous*** was an inappropriate choice of word.

What's wrong with ***meet again***?

Comment: I was using "rendezvous" in the computer science sense (http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Synchronous_rendezvous&redirect=no), so the best I could have done is probably "rendezvous again."